# change destination of IP in windows

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I have a windows machine (A) which uses a software to contact another machine (B) via it's IP, `111.111.111.111`. That IP address is hardcoded inside the software and the problem is that it soon going to change to `222.222.222.222` so I have 2 options:

1. reverse engineer the software to change the hardcoded IP from `111.111.111.111` to `222.222.222.222`.
2. somehow, on the o/s level of (A), make all network calls to IP `111.111.111.111` actually go to `222.222.222.222`.

Is there a solution for #2? I'm thinking something like the `hosts` files in windows, but for IPs. I tried doing it with the `route` command but I did not succeed.

Comment: I would do #1 and change all IPs to hostnames so this problem won't occur again.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen not an option obviously since I'm asking a solution for #2.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can be done in 3 ways:

Install and configure Routing and Remote Access and configure a NAT rule on the device

Configure a NAT rule on the upstream router

Configure a static ARP entry on the server pointing 2.2.2.2 to the servers existing mac address